# C - I don't want to allocate memory that i will not use! (newby question)

Tags: c, string, comments, malloc

I've made my first C program. It strips C comments ('//'). I pass a string to the function strip_comments, create a new string with the same size as the argument string and then i do a copy, char by char, ignoring comments.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define IN 1
#define OUT 0

int file_size(FILE *file);
char * strip_comments(char *content);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *file;
    char *buffer, *content;
    int size;

    if (argc == 1)
    {
        printf("USAGE: stripccomments filename\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if ((file = fopen(argv[1], "rw")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    size = file_size(file);
    buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * size);

    if (buffer == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not allocate memory\n");
        return 1;
    }

    fread(buffer, sizeof(char), size, file);

    content = strip_comments(buffer);
    printf("%s", content);

    free(buffer);
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}

int file_size(FILE *file)
{
    int size;

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(file);
    rewind(file);

    return size;
}

char * strip_comments(char *content)
{
    int state, length, i, j;
    char *new_content;

    state = OUT;
    length = strlen(content);
    new_content = malloc(sizeof(char) * length);
    j = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (content[i] == '/' && content[i + 1] == '/')
        {
            state = IN;
            i++;
            continue;
        }

        if (state && content[i] == '\n')
        {
            state = OUT;
        }

        if (!state)
        {
            new_content[j] = content[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    new_content[j + 1] = '\0';

    return new_content;
}
```

If there are some comments, i will just use some bytes of the allocated string. I don't want to allocate more than i will use. What's the best approach to do that and return a new string? Or should I modify the string passed as parameter?

UPDATE: What happens with this unused space? Does it remain in the "limbo" ? And what happens with this space when execution reach the end?

Thank you.

Comment: Not to discourage you, but stripping comments in C is a bit more involved than that. Imagine how your code will respond to this situation: `char *string = "this is a // string";`

Comment: Remove `sizeof(char)`. All it does is show that the author of the code didn't know C.

Comment: Still learning... now i'm getting discouraged :(

Comment: @R.. - Or change it to `sizeof *buffer`.

Comment: Since you did a #define enumeration, I would suggest you change `if (!state)` to `if(state == OUT)`

Comment: If someone needs help too... About sizeof char: http://drj11.wordpress.com/2007/04/08/sizeofchar-is-1/ . jedwards, i've made what you suggest. Thank you

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `sizeof(char)`. We benefit from following patterns, and the pattern for `malloc` is `(sizeof(thing_to_be_allocated) * number_to_allocate)`. Why unnecessarily confuse the issue by adding exceptions to the rule? You might get the idea that I disagree with the blog post in this regard. You'd be right.

Comment: @Chris Lutz: Or `/* this is a // comment */`

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't solve your problem as stated, but my approach would be to write this as a function that works with an input file handle and output file handle, i.e. `void strip_comments(FILE *infile, FILE *outfile);`. You're really only doing character-at-a-time parsing anyway, so what's to lose switching from `content[i++]` to `getc()`? If you do it with filehandles instead of strings, you a) don't have to store potentially large entire files in memory, and b) don't have to worry about allocating memory for a buffer.

That said, if you want to do it with `char *`s instead, you could always parse through the string twice: once to calculate how many bytes to allocate, then once to copy said bytes over. Or you could simply call `realloc` at the end to shorten your buffer down to the appropriate size.

Comment: I will search about realloc. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since your program will not know how much memory is needed to contain the source you can start with an initial buffer size and increase it as necessary. Another way is to scan the file first and calculate the difference in sizes. Both of these approaches have performance implications depending on the amount of comments passed in. Multiple `malloc`'s/`realloc`'s will slow performance as well as reading through the entire file twice, and on the other hand your worried about wasting memory, it is your choice to decide or you can use all 3, setting a default and then implement command line flags to let the user decide which option if they so choose.

Also remember to add +1 to your strlen to account for the null character. Your current implementation will go into un`malloc`ed territory if the file contains no comments.

**For Your Update:**

Yes the wasted space will be at the end of your string doing nothing but will be properly reclaimed once `free` is called. For instance a string with strlen of 10 in a block of memory allocated for 15 may look like this:

```
size of 10\0#%^@&
          ^^^garbage
          ^^null char
```

Comment: Operation system doesn't "free" when the execution reach the end? Thank you.

Comment: the operating system will clean the memory up in your application space if you leaked it or not on exit. In your example you are leaking memory but a call to free will be able to reclaim all of the memory even if you are not using it all. You should be calling `free(content)` after `printf("%s", content);` in your example since you do nothing else with it.

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of one way that might make your allocation more efficient (not that I think it needs to be, honestly what you're doing now seems pretty reasonable, especially for a new C programmer).

What I can think of is to go through your file in two passes. In the first pass you can calculate the amount of memory that you will need to allocate. After this you can allocate exactly the amount of memory that you need and then in the second pass you do the actual copying.

Also you might benefit from taking a look at making this using file handles instead of doing it entirely in-memory so that you do not need to allocate large swaths of memory at once.

Comment: And what about pointer arithmetic? Can I use that for this task? Thank you!